# Test whether a given set belongs to a given family.

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

There is given family of sets, $\mathcal{F}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(\{1,2,...,m\})$.

$\mathcal{P}(A)$ is a set of all the subsets of $A$.

Consider now an arbitrary set $S\in \mathcal{P}(\{1,2,...,m\})$.

I would like to find an equivalent test to determine whether $$S\in \{X\cap Y: X\in \mathcal{F}, Y\in \mathcal{F}\}$$.

> How to do this?

I look for a simple algebraic tool, that could be useful. I have tried to associate vectors to each set or to create a logical matrix, but this gave me no result.

Regards.

Comment: What's wrong with the obvious algorithm? I'm pretty confident you can show that you can't do much better than it.

Comment: One way is to first disregard all sets that do not contain $S$, and after doing that removing $S$ from all the ones that do. We must then check if there are two that are disjoint. Here is a source to that problem. https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20278/testing-empty-set-intersection